# Python Http Server Code Explanation?

Tags: python, http, sys

I have seen many examples of http servers written in python on the internet and they all include

```
if sys.argv[1:]:
    port = int(sys.argv[1])
else:
    port = 8000
```

Can anyone explain this line to me? Thanks

Comment: If the port is has been provided as an argument then use it. Otherwise use 8000

Answer (score 1):

[`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv) is a list of strings containing the arguments that were passed into a Python script from the commandline.  `sys.argv[0]` is the name of the script and it is always passed in implicitly.  The arguments passed in by the user will be stored in `sys.argv[1]`, `sys.argv[2]`, etc.

With this in mind, the code can be explained as follows:

```
# If there is more than 1 item in sys.argv...
if sys.argv[1:]:
    # ...get sys.argv[1], convert it into an integer, and assign it to port
    port = int(sys.argv[1])
# Otherwise, assign port to 8000
else:
    port = 8000
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `sys.argv` is a list containing the command line arguments: if you start the program like this: `./foo one two 3`, the list will contain the values `['./foo', 'one', 'two', '3']`
2. `mylist[a:]` is a part of the list `mylist` starting at index `a` up to the last element
3. `if list` is true if the list is not empty
4. all in all: `port` is set to 8000 if it's not specified as the first command line argument

Comment: You forgot about `sys.argv[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, this code is setting the post used to communicate with whatever computer made the request. 8000 is the default TCP port, so that's what it will use if no port was specified.